# Is there a way to get all services in use in AWS using cli/api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I need to find a way (using AWS CLI or Python ergo AWS SDK) to retrieve all services in use by account X. Is that possible? If it is is it an integrated feature or does it needs iterating all the services?

Comment: I don't think there is any direct API, you might need to loop through all AWS services and see if any resources allocated for the account.

Comment: how can i do that? Can you point me to a command or something. Im quite new with CLI

Comment: Wonder if cost explorer has CLI, anything that's billing non-zero is in use.

Comment: @RaGe it has a cli but it does not account for free tier